# TypeScript output isn't being combined

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-4.5

I have the following setup:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "none",
        "outFile": "js/app.js"
    }
}
```

**MyApp.Main.ts**

```
class Main
{
    constructor()
    {
        Utilities.init(this);
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

**MyApp.Utilities.ts**

```
class Utilities
{
    static init(app: Main)
    {
         // Do something with app...
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

When I either save the .ts file or recompile the project, I do not have an `app.js` file as specified in the `outFile` option, I only get `MyApp.Main.js` and `MyApp.Utilities.js` compiled files.

I have also tried adding `/// <reference ... />` paths to my "Main" class, and that also does not cause outputs to be combined.

Some notes:

- I can't target a newer ES version because I need to support IE without a shim.
- Similarly, I cannot use a module system because I am not allowed to introduce an additional dependency into the project, so the module must be "none".
- I can't run the code through an additional compiler such as Babel.

Basically, I need to get this to work with pure TypeScript, no module system, and no (default) ES target.

What am I doing wrong that the outputs are not being combined into a single .js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html (in the description of `--module` option)

> Only "AMD" and "System" can be used in conjunction with --outFile.

So you should change `module` setting as described.

Usually if TS maintainers say things like this, there is no way to overcome it (and you shouldn't).

> I am not allowed to introduce an additional dependency into the
>   project

What kind of dependency is it? Modules don't force you to add any.

Comment: I was under the impression that introducing a module system would require you to include the actual module library (e.g. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js) - is this not true? That's what I meant by dependency.

Comment: Nope, nowadays one usually adds as a *devDependency* (which adds zero KBs to your app) a bundler like Parcel or Webpack that converts modules to browser-compatible code (bundle). In other words, after `tsc` you also should run a bundler's command (`parcel` or something)

Comment: You don’t need a module system to bundle separate ts files into one single js file. TSC already does that.

Comment: You are correct but only for when `--outFile` is used (OP's case)

Comment: True, but this answer suggests that a module system is needed to solve the problem. Since the OP specifically asks not to introduce new dependencies, it seems better to leave out the module setting altogether.

Answer (score -1):

You can just leave out the module option and it should work!

This is my tsconfig.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noUnusedLocals":true,
    "noUnusedParameters":true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "docs/js/main.js"
},
  "include": [
    "dev/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Erm, if you downvote, please add an explanation. The accepted answer suggests you need modules and a bundler, which is incorrect for this question. TSC already bundles ts files into one js file by itself.